# MVC Devexpress Gridview disable specific column hiding

Tags: gridview, devexpress

How to disable MVC Devexpress Gridview specific column hiding in Customization Window or set minimal column count which are not allowed to hide in the Customization Window

Answer (score 1):

Set the **MVCxColumn.Settings.AllowDragDrop** property to "**DefaultBoolean.False**" to prevent column from moving to/from the Customization Window:

```
@Html.DevExpress().GridView(
    settings => {
        ...
        settings.Columns.Add(...).Settings.AllowDragDrop = DefaultBoolean.False;
    }).Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```